# How can i update my database from another database using temporary tables?

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, temporary-tables

I want to update tables of my database using another big database every day with using temporary tables and without returning result. How can i update it?

This my temporary table :

```
use data_pro; 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS datasll.table1;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS datasll.table1 
SELECT 
 cs.id,
 cs.fk_c,
 cs.so, 
 cs.pr,
 cs.date,
 cs.o_p,
 cs.sh_c,
 cs.x,
 LEFT(cs.x,2),
 cs.doc,
 cs.fk_op,
 cc.id_c_c,
 cc.name,
 cc.descrip,
 left(cc.n_o,3) as bon,
 cc.fk_c_br,
 cc.de,
 cc.m_mat,
 cc.color, 
 cc.fk_c_s
 FROM
   data_pro.catas cs

 LEFT OUTER JOIN
data_pro.c_co cc ON  data_pro.cs.fk_c_c = data_pro.cc._id_cc
WHERE
data_pro.cc.pap = 1 AND   data_pro.cc.stati = 'b';

Many thanks for any help.
```

Comment: Your request is unclear to me. Please describe the results you want.

Comment: i want to write a script to update my database using stored procedure. My procedure works with displaying all rows. i want my procedure update my database without diplayin all results that's mean returning all rows without dsplay it.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed use stored procedures to refresh the data in your database.  It just means coding the INSERTs and UPDATEs appropriate to your data.

If you are replacing the existing data with new data, you could use:

`INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM` ... syntax, after deleting the existing data, to pull the data from your query and insert it into the now empty table. Of course, you could run individual steps to update many tables, one at a time.

Syntax documentation on `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM` is here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html

If you want to `UPDATE ... SELECT FROM` for only some values in a table, you could follow the different examples here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262786/mysql-update-query-based-on-select-query

Also general `UPDATE` syntax is described here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: i use a database "datasll" to update the tables of "data_pro",because in "data_pro" i can't insert or modify or delete just select. So i really want to update many tables, one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to make a new entry means, You can just do

Insert into tablename 
select query

If you want to update your table based on some values, but the values are need to took from some other table through joining(Select query which you mentioned)you can store those values in temp table.And then you can iterate those values through do-while or Cursor and you can update the destination table(table to be updated).

Temp table Creation

Declare @TempTableName table
(
Column1 datatype,
.
.
ColumnN dataTyPE
)

Insert into @TempTableName
Select query mentioned in your comments.

Iterate the table and update the destination table.
See cursors in sql for iterating temp table.

vote if the answer was helpful.

Comment: i use a database "datasll" to update the tables of  "data_pro",because in "data_pro" i can't insert or modify or delete juste select.

Comment: Could you please elloborate your exact requirement.So that i may help exactly what you need.In which database you are going to retrieve values and in which database you are going to update the tables

Comment: retreive values from data_pro and update tables in datasll.

Comment: Ok then what was the problem arises. Retieve the values from data_pro database and then insert them into the temp table . Iterate the temp table and update those values in datasll database(datasll.dbo.Table_name).Let me know if it was unclear

Comment: Thank for all your answers. So the solution is to use a temporary table not stored procedure but how i can update those values in datasll? i really need your help because i have a lot of tables to update.

Comment: My tmp table : use data_pro;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS datasll.table1;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS datasll.table1
SELECT 
     cs.id,
     cs.fk_c,
     cs.so, 
     cs.pr,
     cs.date,
     cs.o_p,
     cs.sh_c,
     cs.x,
     LEFT(cs.x,2),
     cs.doc,
     cs.fk_op,
     cc.id_c_c,
     cc.name,
     cc.descrip,
     left(cc.n_o,3) as bon,
     cc.fk_c_br,
     cc.de,
     cc.m_mat,
     cc.color, 
     cc.fk_c_s
     FROM
       data_pro.catas cs

LEFT OUTER JOIN data_pro.c_co cc ON  data_pro.cs.fk_c_c = data_pro.cc._id_cc
WHERE
data_pro.cc.pap = 1 AND   data_pro.cc.stati = 'b';

Comment: i create my temporary table using data_pro and affected records is 880000 but how can iterate the temp table and update those values in datasll database?

Comment: You can use Cursor to iterate those records one by one but am not sure whether iteraing through a cusror will be an optimal option as your record count was too large

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25141/discussion-between-selva-and-sarah).